# How can use rdlc report with Oracle procedure?

Tags: rdlc

Can any one help to solve creating reports of rdlc using Oracle stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

RDLC accepts object (POCO, StrongTyped DataSet, ...) as data source. So it doesn't matter where data source comes from.

Comment: I am not able to add oracle dataset for rdlc. Can u help me how can i use oracle database for rdlc. If u provide the steps it would heighly appreciated.